# Rotate and change image after clicking on it

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-effects

I have a picture of the front page of a book. When I click on it I want the image to change to the back page.

I created something with jQuery , but it is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/MEHhs/

```
<div id="picture_here">
     <img src="http://www.sbtjapan.com/img/FaceBook_img.jpg" id="picture"/>
</div>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: correct image url..images are not there.

Comment: The markup and js is correct, except the back page is a private image which throughs a js error. Ensure that your back page image is a public image. http://jsfiddle.net/TKJR3/